# How to store a few hundred sets of generated vectors and to be able to pull out and observe their contents later on?

Tags: matlab

set of 30 numbers that have been stored inside a vector `d`
for example.

`d = [ 3 5 7 2 7 8 .....]`

However the numbers inside will shuffled around constantly for a few hundred iterations.
The following is what is used to shuffle the numbers

`i = randperm(length(d));

d = d(i);`

using a loop to shuffle it as many times as is needed to.

Is there a method to store or record all the different results of the shuffle and to be able to view the contents later?

For example, having the need to check what was the arrangement of the `37th` shuffle and compare it with the `45th`.

The amount of numbers stored inside `"d"`  could changed depending on circumstance..
sorry for my weak understanding of this subject. Appreciated any help in this matter..

Comment: probably you can save to file and then load them for comparison...http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html

Answer (score 2):

You can save the results by saving them in a matrix.
Start with `s = d`.
Then after each iteration, you can append `s` with

```
s = [s ; d];
```

If you want to view the 2nd iteration afterwards, type `s(2,:)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can store them in a matrix, where each row represent a single permutation.

```
d   = [original number vector];
num = number of random permutations needed;

perms        = zeros(num, len(d));
perms(1, :)  = d;

for i = 2:num
    p = randperm(len(d));
    prerms(i, :) = perms(i-1, p);
```

Comment: hi there! thanks for your help!
i tried doing that but when i did your suggestion they gave me this warning. 
for this line
`perms        = zeros(num, d); `  

`Warning: Input arguments must be
scalar. `
is it because `d` is a vector and is causing problems?

Comment: Sorry, that shoud be zeros(num, len(d)); I edited it now... Thanks for the feedback.